# get the context of a created canvas with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createelement

I'm trying to use this methods ( http://jsfiddle.net/erickzanardo/RHZL6/ ) to create a canvas with createElement and then draw on it, but since I'm using JQuery the canvas so created deosn't have a class function getContext("2d"), but it seems to work on the last jsfiddle.
My code is as follow :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  var map_rendered = document.createElement("map");
  map_rendered.heigt = 100 ; map_rendered.width = 100 ;
  var map_rendered_ctx = map_rendered.getContext("2d");
```

the error I get is :

```
TypeError: map_rendered.getContext is not a function
```

Do you have a way to solve it, or any other method to create a pre-rendered map, my aim is then to display a subsection of this map in a smaller canvas.
Thanks.

Comment: `map_rendered` is a `<map>` element. You must use a `<canvas>` element if you hope `.getContext('2d');` to succeed.

Comment: Also this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change "map" to "canvas", and error will gone

```js
  var map_rendered = document.createElement("canvas");
  map_rendered.heigt = 100 ;
  map_rendered.width = 100 ;
  var map_rendered_ctx = map_rendered.getContext("2d");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I thought we could give an arbitrary name in the function createElement.